# Method to return Text from an element using playwright c#

Tags: c#, playwright

Using X-unit and C#
I want to locate an element then assert that its text value matches a particular string

i would do the following using selenium:

```
IWebElement userButton 
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("button.user- 
icon"));
Assert.Equal("testString", userButton.Text);
```

in playwright im doing the following:

```
var userButton = page.Locator("button.user-icon");
Assert.Equal("testString", userButton.?);
```

I can find the element successfully but the ? shows where I cant find any method that returns the string value of the element, there are things like getByText but nothing similar to the dot Text method available in selenium.

ive tried the following also:

```
    await 
Expect(Page.Locator("button.usericon")).ToHaveTextAsync("testString");
```

but i get an error telling me that Expect does not exist in the current context. I believe this comes from the playwright.Nunit Library but im using Xunit

```
 Is there a method that can be called on an element to return its text value?
```

Comment: Apparently Selenium `IWebElement.Text` returns `innerText` (why change the name?) and so in PlayWright you would use the `Locator.InnerText()` method.

Comment: did you mean Locator.InnerTextAsync(); ? I can not see Locator.InnerText() on my locator object. The method i found did work for me though.  Assert.Equal("testString", await page.Locator("button.user-icon").InnerTextAsync());                                                                       This might not be the best way to do it however

Answer (score 0):

Playwright recommends to use their assertions, since they retry until either the timeout is reached or the condition is met.

Normal assertions like Assert.Equal don't retry.

See here: https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/test-assertions#locator-assertions-to-have-text

For your use-case it would be the following:

```
var locator = Page.Locator(".title");
await Expect(locator).ToHaveTextAsync("Welcome, Test User");
```